# Assign 2 values to whole array of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays

This might be the silly question but i want quick solution for this.

I have default colors array:

foreg : `defColors = ['green', 'yellow'];`

and I have another array of column

`cols = ['lowest', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'highest'];`

I have the the values for first three items in `cols` array like this.

`filler = ['lowest': 'darkred', 'low': 'red'];`

And now i want to assign values to rest of value of `cols` array and make it look like this:

`filler = [lowest: 'darkred', low: 'red', medium: 'green', high: 'yellow', highest: 'green']`

This might be tricky but I want exactly like this, so if default colors has 2 items it assign its value in loop for all remaining items from col items.

Note: I also have an array for col items that doesn't have its value assigned like this:

`remainingKeys = ['medium', 'high', 'highest'];`

Comment: `filler = [lowest: darkred, low: red];` Is this an array of strings or an object? The way you have it is not syntactically valid JavaScript.

Comment: @gyre, I was too lazy to add quotes, they are all strings

Comment: Your `filler` array is incorrect

Comment: @gyre, Is it now correct?

Comment: If you want to create an object, the outer brackets should be `{}` instead of `[]`

Comment: @gyre, actually I am going to use different arrays for both key and values, for `d3.scaleOrdinal().domain().range()`

Comment: So what kind of data structure are you creating? Is it two parallel arrays, one for keys and one for values, or is it one array containing a bunch of key-value pairs (arrays of length 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over your `remainingKeys` and update the properties of the `filler` object (note that, since it is not an array, it should be enclosed in curly brackets rather than square ones). The [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) (`%`) is useful here for selecting a color from your `defColors` array in a repeating pattern.

```js
var defColors = ['green', 'yellow']
var cols = ['lowest', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'highest']
var filler = {'lowest': 'darkred', 'low': 'red'}
var remainingKeys = ['medium', 'high', 'highest'];


remainingKeys.forEach(function (key, i) {
  this[key] = defColors[i % defColors.length]
}, filler)

console.log(filler)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but since I wasn't aware of it until a short while ago, I thought I would share some knowledge. `%` is the [Remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_%28%29), which is subtly different from a modulo operator (the difference has to do with the way negative numbers are handled).. JS currently doesn't have a true modulo operator, but there is a [proposal to add one](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:modulo_operator).

Comment: I appreciate you sharing that distinction; I was already aware that `%` differed from mathematical `mod` in that way but did not know that convention was to call it the "remainder operator" instead. Do note that in this case the difference is irrelevant because neither `i` nor `defColors.length` can ever be negative.